# Rails doesn't load actionform gem from Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

My Rails 4.2 app fails to load some GitHub hosted gem (installed via bundler v1.8.2). I am using rvm 1.26.10 (master)

In my `Gemfile`,

`gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'actionform', :github => 'rails/actionform'`

Bundler install them in different location:
`$ bundle show simple_form
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@my_app/gems/simple_form-3.1.0`

`$ bundle show actionform
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@my_app/bundler/gems/actionform-4a858fecf4c2`

Rails never load the `actionform` gem.
After inserting the line `//= require action_form` to my `app/assets/javascript/application.js` file, this error comes

> Sprockets::FileNotFound at / couldn't find file 'action_form'
>   However, the `action_form.js` file exists in the gem file.

Moreover, when i try to reproduce the readme example, i got this error

> NameError at /conferences/new uninitialized constant ActionForm

`require 'bundler/setup'` is in `boot.rb`

Any advise about this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything works if i use the old `m-Peter/activeform`. Posting this question to actionform's github [issue](https://github.com/rails/actionform/issues/37)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a mismatch between the gem name and the file inside the gem. Because the gem is named 'actionform', Bundler will try to `require 'actionform'`, however the file is actually called `action_form`.

You can tell Bundler the right file name with this syntax:

```
gem 'actionform', :github => 'rails/actionform', :require => 'action_form'
```

Note that it is normal for gems from git sources to be installed into a different location than gems installed from gem servers. It has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Great! I'd suggest editing the title of the question to something more like "Rails doesn't load actionform gem from my Gemfile" to make it easier for other people with the same problem to find it in the future.